# order by em subquerys oracle

Tags: query, oracle, pl-sql, order

## RESOLVIDO

Resolvi da seguinte maneira, criei uma view igual a minha tabela de ordens de serviço mais que era ordenada pela equipe e pela prioridade, e ai mantive a query acima trocando somente a tabela da subquery que eu coloquei a view que eu criei, dessa forma não preciso me preocupar com a ordenação porque o oracle vai trazer da forma que a view traz e a view ja traz ordenado então deu certinho, pelo menos por enquanto... muito obrigado por todos que tentaram ajudar e se por um acaso souberem de uma forma melhor de resolver o meu problema não deixe de me responder :D

########################################################################

eu achei algumas perguntas por aqui parecidas com a minha mais nenhuma das respostas me ajudou, eu tenho a seguinte situação:

Uma tabela com ordens de serviço, imaginemos que ela tenha apenas 5 campos que são: ORDEM_ID | EQUIPE_MANUT | DATA_ABERTURA | PRIORI | OBSERVACAO.

E eu preciso montar um painel web que vai exibir as 5 O.S com valor PRIORI mais baixo de cada equipe.

ex:

```
ORDEM_ID | EQUIPE_MANUT | DATA_ABERTURA | PRIORI | OBSERVACAO
  0001        100           01/01/2017      1          aaaa
  0002        100           01/01/2017      2          aaaa
  0003        100           01/01/2017      3          aaaa
  0004        100           01/01/2017      4          aaaa
  0005        100           01/01/2017      5          aaaa
  0006        105           01/01/2017      1          aaaa
  0007        105           01/01/2017      2          aaaa
  0008        105           01/01/2017      3          aaaa
  0009        105           01/01/2017      4          aaaa
  0010        105           01/01/2017      5          aaaa
```

Bom eu consegui listar apenas 5 O.S de cada EQUIPE_MANUT o problema começa quando eu tento retornar os 5 com o valor PRIORI mais baixo, vou mostrar a query que eu tenho utlizado:

```
SELECT ORDEM_ID   AS ORDEM,
  DATA_ABERTURA   AS DATA_ABERTURA,
  C1.EQUIPE_MANUT AS EQUIPE,
  TRANSLATE(C1.OBSERVACAO,'âàãáÁÂÀÃéêÉÊíÍóôõÓÔÕüúÜÚÇç','AAAAAAAAEEEEIIOOOOOOUUUUCC') AS OBSERVACAO
FROM CORDEMSERV C1
WHERE C1.ORDEM_ID IN
  (SELECT C2.ORDEM_ID
    FROM CORDEMSERV C2
    WHERE C2.EQUIPE_MANUT = C1.EQUIPE_MANUT
    AND C2.STATUS         ='1'
    AND C2.PRIO          IS NOT NULL
    AND ROWNUM <=5 
  )
AND C1.STATUS='1'
AND C1.PRIO IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY C1.EQUIPE_MANUT;
```

Eu já tentei colocar essa subquery dentro de outra subquery sem o rownum e utiliza-lo depois dos dados já ordenados mais ai eu não consigo ligar C1.EQUIPE_MANUT com a C2.EQUIPE_MANUT acho eu que devido ser uma subquery que ja  dentro de outra subquery ... bom é isso se alguém puder me ajudar :D

Comment: essa query funciona, pelo que entendi só falta a ordenação correta, certo?

Comment: sim, só falta a ordenação, mais o oracle não me permite colocar um order by ali na subquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira, criei uma view igual a minha tabela de ordens de serviço mais que era ordenada pela equipe e pela prioridade, e ai mantive a query acima trocando somente a tabela da subquery que eu coloquei a view que eu criei, dessa forma não preciso me preocupar com a ordenação porque o oracle vai trazer da forma que a view traz e a view ja traz ordenado então deu certinho, pelo menos por enquanto... muito obrigado por todos que tentaram ajudar e se por um acaso souberem de uma forma melhor de resolver o meu problema não deixe de me responder :D

Answer (score 0):

Assim para o que você precisa funciona:

```
with ordens_result as (select Ordem_Id, Equipe_Manut from Cordemserv where Status = '1' and Prio is not null order by Equipe_Manut, Prio)
select C1.Ordem_Id as Ordem
      ,C1.Data_Abertura as Data_Abertura
      ,C1.Equipe_Manut as Equipe
      ,Translate(C1.Observacao, 'âàãáÁÂÀÃéêÉÊíÍóôõÓÔÕüúÜÚÇç', 'AAAAAAAAEEEEIIOOOOOOUUUUCC') as Observacao
  from Cordemserv C1
 where C1.Ordem_Id in (select Ordem_Id from ordens_result
                        where Equipe_Manut = C1.Equipe_Manut
                          and Rownum <= 5)
   and C1.Status = '1'
   and C1.Prio is not null
 order by C1.Equipe_Manut
         ,C1.Prio;
```

**Update:**
utilizado o recurso With para fazer a ordenação.

(old)Aplicado função analítica, aonde eu pego o max id particionado pela equipe e ordenado pela prioridade da equipe.

Comment: pelo que vi você só colocou o order by na query principal correto? isso não resolve o problema por que eu preciso ordenar os resultados da subquery e nao da query principal imagina que uma equipe tenha 10 O.S qnd eu pego as 5 na subquery eu to pegando 5 das 10 mais nao necessariamente as 5 com a priori menor entendeu??

Comment: Entendi, vou montar o cenário aqui

Comment: Mas no teu cenário, faz mais sentido pegar as 5 com maior prioridade, não? pq senão pode vir um item que não era tão prioritário assim

Comment: nós utilizamos o conceito de que qnt menor o valor de prioridade maior é a prioridade por exemplo, uma O.S com prioridade 1 é a nossa maior prioridade e quanto maior o numero menos prioritária ela é...

Comment: Achei a solução, acho que valeu uma coxinha hahaha

Comment: infelizmente não resolve dessa forma alem dele retornar um único resultado pra cada equipe ele ainda não trouxe a O.S mais prioritária euheueh'

Comment: Aqui funcionou, criei a mesma ideia de tabelas... vou analisar ;/

Comment: Está usando oracle 11g?

Comment: não o 10g......

Comment: é possível ter a mesma prioridade para mais de um id na mesma equipe?

Comment: sim é possível mais nesse momento não tem... esse link  http://imgur.com/a/Q2YdU  é de uma imagem de como ficou pra vc ter uma idéia... na parte de cima é com uma solução que arrumei usando views e na parte de baixo o resultado com a sua solução...   assim meu problema esta resolvido mais se tiver uma solução melhor que a view eu aceito haha' tenho muitas O.S entçao qualquer coisa que for mais rapido pra mim é melhor...

Comment: cara, era pra funcionar, adicionei o asc (que eu me lembro ele é default) testa por favor

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64292/discussion-between-damon-dudek-and-edilson-pereira).